# pull data from one column into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as:

**Table_1**

```
Question01  Answer01   Question02  Answer02     QuestionN   AnswerN
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Favourite     Red      Favourite     Chips      Favourite     Black Beatles
Colour?                Food?                    Song?
```

**Table_2**

```
No.       
----------
Question01  
Question02  
...
QuestionN
```

And I want to get a result that looks like this:

```
No.       | Questions 
----------
Question01  Favourite Colour?
Question02  Favourite Food?
...
QuestionN   Favourite Song?
```

I need the resulting table to be dynamic as the number of questions can vary.
Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Do you really have that many columns for questions and answers?

Comment: It could be any number columns because the number of questions will vary

Comment: Surely you'd have just stored table 1 as "Question" "Answer" and have many lines of questions with their answers..

Comment: Google `SQL SERVER Dynamic UNPIVOT`

Comment: select q1, a1 union all q2, a2 union all ... qn, an

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql and unpivot for this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @column_list NVARCHAR(max) = N''

SELECT @column_list += QUOTENAME(q) + ',' FROM Table_2 
SET @column_list = SUBSTRING(@column_list, 1, LEN(@column_list) -1)

SET @sql = CONCAT(N'
SELECT up.[No.], up.[Questions] FROM (
    SELECT
        ',@column_list,N' 
    FROM Table_1
) p
UNPIVOT ([No.] FOR [Questions] IN (',@column_list,N')) AS up')

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!